Presenting Share option working only when debbug executable is enabled - iOS - React Native
In a react native application share feature is implemented in ios native. UIDocumentInteraction controller is used to show share window.
The below code is written as a action selector for a UIBarButton.
@objc fileprivate func shareTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let pageURL = extractPageFromDocument(document, forPageNumber: Int(pageIndex), withName: "share-report-page.pdf") {
      documentInteractionController.url = pageURL
      documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: sender, animated: true)
    }
  }

The code is working perfectly fine when the debug executable is enabled in xcode scheme.
When debug executable enabled, this screen seems.
Same code is producing crash when running the app with debug executable disabled in xcode. Crash log is below.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SHSheetPresenter applyOptionsOnWillMoveToParentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000038bea00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114423531 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110ea37e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114438643 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114427cc4 ___forwarding___ + 1459
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114429ec8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   OneViewNew                          0x00000001059161b5 -[UIViewController(LayoutProtocol) willMoveToParentViewController:] + 133
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000137be2b6c -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 691
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000137afde44 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1782
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000137afd594 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 992
    9   ShareSheet                          0x000000012ae7fa2a -[SHSheetRouter presentMainViewController:withNavigationControllerSupport:] + 252
    10  ShareSheet                          0x000000012ae33707 -[SHSheetPresenter prepareViewIfNeeded] + 714
    11  ShareSheet                          0x000000012ae1a7ca -[UIActivityViewController viewDidLoad] + 110
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bd7e1a -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 80
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bddf12 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1342
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bde2f9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bf690c -[UIViewController _setPresentationController:] + 92
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bee745 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1472
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bf20b1 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4488
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011442a15c __invoking___ + 140
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114427483 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 302
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000137bebd8e -[UIViewController _endDelayingPresentation] + 441
    21  ShareSheet                          0x000000012ae1b5f2 -[UIActivityViewController _endDelayingPresentation] + 229
    22  ShareSheet                          0x000000012ae0a656 -[SHSheetScene scene:didReceiveActions:] + 589
    23  FrontBoard                          0x000000012d082630 -[FBSceneObserver scene:didReceiveActions:] + 104
    24  FrontBoard                          0x000000012d080457 __57-[FBSceneWorkspace scene:didReceiveActions:forExtension:]_block_invoke + 1212
    25  BaseBoard                           0x000000011f19770c -[BSEventQueue _processNextEvent] + 294
    26  BaseBoard                           0x000000011f197b5d -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvents:atPosition:] + 778
    27  BaseBoard                           0x000000011f1977fc -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvent:atPosition:] + 112
    28  FrontBoard                          0x000000012d07c829 -[FBSceneWorkspace _executeNextIdleEventIfAppropriate] + 303
    29  FrontBoard                          0x000000012d07c6ed -[FBSceneWorkspace _executeEventWhenIdle:] + 98
    30  FrontBoard                          0x000000012d07fe55 -[FBSceneWorkspace scene:didReceiveActions:forExtension:] + 684
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114f643ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114f656d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114f7448c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1420
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114f73ef2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011437faf4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011437a42f __CFRunLoopRun + 2463
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001143796ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011f92e08f GSEventRunModal + 137
    39  UIKitCore                           0x00000001385c8ad1 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    40  UIKitCore                           0x00000001385cd551 UIApplicationMain + 123
    41  OneViewNew                          0x0000000104d5cf1f main + 63
    42  dyld                                0x00000001103023e0 start_sim + 10
    43  ???                                 0x0000000207bf8345 0x0 + 8719926085
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Tried debugging with exception breakpoint and debugger hit at the below place at "UIViewController+LayoutProtocol" before crash.
(https://i.sstatic.net/QG9FrjnZ.png)
Self.presenter value here is:
<SHSheetPresenter: 0x7fa3569125f0>

and resolveOptions is nil.
